# Adding syntax highlighting rules to AvalonEdit programmatically

Tags: syntax-highlighting, avalonedit

I'm using AvalonEdit in an app that runs my own custom-built language. I want to put in appropriate syntax highlighting into Avalon Edit. Normally this is done by defining the highlighting rules in an xml file by hand.

However, I don't want the highlighting rules to always be falling out of sync with the language grammar whenever I extend the language. So I'm hoping to use the grammar info that's already contained in my coco/R parser to automatically generate these rules.
So is there a way to programmatically add syntax highlighting rules to Avalon Edit?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The below code worked for me  at least.

```cs
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (Stream s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Your.xshd"))
{
    using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(s))
    {
        //Load default Syntax Highlighting
        InternalEditor.SyntaxHighlighting = HighlightingLoader.Load(reader, HighlightingManager.Instance);

        // Dynamic syntax highlighting for your own purpose
        var rules = InternalEditor.SyntaxHighlighting.MainRuleSet.Rules;

        _HighlightingRule = new HighlightingRule();
        _HighlightingRule.Color = new HighlightingColor()
        {
                Foreground = new CustomizedBrush(SomeColor)
        };

        String[] wordList = PseudoGetKeywords(); // Your own logic
        String regex = String.Format(@"\b({0})\w*\b", String.Join("|", wordList));
        _HighlightingRule.Regex = new Regex(regex);

        rules.Add(_HighlightingRule);
    }
}


internal sealed class CustomizedBrush : HighlightingBrush
{
    private readonly SolidColorBrush brush; 
    public CustomizedBrush(Color color)
    {
        brush = CreateFrozenBrush(color);
    }

    public CustomizedBrush(System.Drawing.Color c)
    {
        var c2 = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(c.A, c.R, c.G, c.B);        
        brush = CreateFrozenBrush(c2);
    }

    public override Brush GetBrush(ITextRunConstructionContext context)
    {
        return brush;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return brush.ToString();
    }

    private static SolidColorBrush CreateFrozenBrush(Color color)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        brush.Freeze();
        return brush;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can generate an .xshd file in memory using the object model in `ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Highlighting.Xshd` (`XshdSyntaxDefinition` etc.).

To convert it into an `IHighlightingDefinition`, use the `HighlightingLoader.Load()` method. You can also save it to disk (for debugging purposes) by applying the `SaveXshdVisitor`.

Alternatively, you could implement `IHighlightingDefinition` yourself and directly create `HighlightingRuleSet` instances.